# Skrollr does not work in IOS, although i've wrapper the body with Skrollr Body

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, skrollr

I have been developing a website using `Skrollr` `v.0.6.17`.
During the testing, I found out that the website does not work with IOS devices. The pages on the website could not be scrolled and locked. I have implemented `Skrollr` to wrap all the body section, except the one with fixed positioning. It still did not work, but I found out that my `video embed` would allow me to scroll the page, which was strange.

The website is http://encore.andrewtaswin.com/

Could any one provide me any help in this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
html {height:100%}
```

I have to admit though that it was not obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help! much appreciated! now it works perfectly.

Comment: Prinz, I found out that using Skrollr-body tag would break all in-page anchor because it does not actually scroll the page. Any idea how I could work this out? Thanks.